# emacs opens from Windows start menu but not terminal

Tags: microsoft-windows, start-up

I upgraded a few months ago to Emacs 29.1. Everything appeared to work until I tried to open Emacs from a terminal.

Here is the error message

```
Warning: arch-independent data dir 'c:/Program Files/Emacs/x86_64/share/emacs/27.2/etc/': No such file or directory
Warning: Lisp directory 'c:/Program Files/Emacs/x86_64/share/emacs/27.2/lisp': No such file or directory
Error: c:/Program Files/Emacs/x86_64/share/emacs/27.2/etc/charsets: No such file or directory
Emacs will not function correctly without the character map files.
Please check your installation!
```

It appears that the terminal isn't aware of the upgrade from version 27.2 to 29.1. How do I finish the installation of 29.1?

Comment: How did you upgrade Emacs?

Comment: Is this a Windows-native terminal and shell?  (And if not, what are you using?)

Comment: if you run 'emacs --version' in terminal?  Seem it still run old emacs exe but it's partialy uninstalled?

Comment: I used the windows installer from gnu.org to install 29.1.

Comment: I'm using the Windows terminal app. I tried running emacs --version in the terminal and now find that I've created a new problem. Now the error is "not recognized as a cmdlet..." I had changed the path thinking that was the problem. Same behavior in the emacs shell and the windows shell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the path variable. I changed the path to point to the location of emacs.exe C:\Program Files\Eamcs\emacs-29.1\bin.

I can open emacs from a windows terminal now.

Thank you commenters. I couldn't have solved the problem without your comments.